# How do I get output to the webpage while still inside a cfscript?

Tags: html, coldfusion, flush, cfml, lucee

Sorry for the longer post, I'm trying to be specific.  I'm a bit of a newb at cold fusion and lucee, so forgive me if I have missed something fundamental here.  I'm just trying to do a quick POC, but can't get it working.
 What I am trying to do is make a page call, write to a web page, sleep for a while.  Kind of a heartbeat.  What I can't get to happen is the write to the web page...until all sleep(s) have happened and the page cfm file completes processing.  I've looked extensively for the past couple of days, and have tried numerous items, but to no avail.
  From my index.cfm lucee page, I have a link to launch a new tab and call my cfm file.
`<a href="./pinger2.cfm" target="_blank"><img class="ploverride" src="/assets/img/Ping.png" alt="Ping Test" width="125" height="75">`
No problem here, a new tab opens and pinger2.cfm starts processing.
What I'm hoping for is the table heading to almost immediately print to the page, then make the first call out, print the results to the page, sleep, make the next call out, print to the page...but it no workey.  Anyone have a clue?  The code in the pinger2.cfm file is:

```
<cfscript>
    public struct function pinger( required string url, required string verb, required numeric timeout, struct body )
    {
        var result = {
            success = false,
            errorMessage = ""
        };
        var httpService = new http();
        httpService.setMethod( arguments.verb );
        httpService.setUrl( arguments.url );
        httpService.setTimeout( arguments.timeout );
        if( arguments.verb == "post" || arguments.verb == "put" )
        {
            httpService.addParam(type="body", value=SerializeJSON(arguments.body));
        }
        try {
            callStart = getTickCount();
            var resultObject = httpService.send().getPrefix();
            callEnd = getTickCount();
            callLength = (callEnd-callStart)/1000;
            if( isDefined("resultObject.status_code") && resultObject.status_code == 200 )
            {
                result.success = true;
                logMessage = "Pinger took " & toString( callLength ) & " seconds.";
                outLine = "<tr><td>" & resultObject.charset &  "</td><td>" & resultObject.http_version  & "</td><td>" & resultObject.mimetype  & "</td><td>" & resultObject.status_code  & "</td><td>" & resultObject.status_text  & "</td><td>" & resultObject.statuscode  & "</td><td>" & logMessage & "</td></tr>";
                writeOutput( outLine );
                getPageContext().getOut().flush();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw("Status Code returned " & resultObject.status_code);
            }
        }
        catch(Any e) {
            // something went wrong with the request
            writeDump( e ); 
            abort;
        }
    }
    outLine = "<table><tr><th>charset</th>  <th>http_version</th>     <th>mimetype</th>      <th>status_code</th>      <th>status_text</th>      <th>statuscode</th>      <th>time</th> </tr>";
    writeOutput( outLine );
    getPageContext().getOut().flush();
    intCounter = 0;
    while(intCounter LT 2) 
    {
        theResponse = pinger(
            url = "https://www.google.com",
            verb = "GET",
            timeout = 5
        );
        intCounter = intCounter + 1;
        getPageContext().getOut().flush();
        sleep(2000);
    }
outLine = "</table>";
writeOutput( outLine );
</cfscript>
```

NOTE:  I'm sure there are other "less than best" practices in there, but I'm just trying to do this quick and dirty.
I thought the `getPageContext().getOut().flush();` would do the trick, but no bueno.
EDIT:  If it matters, I'm using CF version 10,0,0,0 and Lucee version 4.5.2.018.

Comment: To flush the contents of the buffer to the output stream you should just be able to call the cfscript version of `cfflush`, which would just be `flush;`

Comment: Also, in the about you can use the cfscript version of `cfhttp`, e.g. `http url="..." method="...";`, etc... but that is Lucee specific and not ACF compatible.

Comment: I tried that as well, it didn't work. I also used flush;flush; (header and body), but that didn't work.

Comment: Might be the setup of the application server, which will depend on how it was installed. Is it a "standard" install using the installer from the Lucee website?

Comment: Yes, completely standard, I haven't changed anything post install (except a timeout value).

Comment: You also need to make sure you're flushing enough such that the browser will actually render. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945243/cfflush-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-chrome-and-ie however, once i updated to railo, and now lucee, this no longer works for me either. I just haven't investigated why because it hasn't been a problem yet.

Comment: I would suggest raising it over on the dev.lucee.org forum and see if someone from the Lucee team can assist.

Comment: Which web server are you using and how is it connected to your Lucee/ACF servers? This can affect flush operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar to generate ETags by hand (using Lucee 4.5). I stick a simple

`GetPageContext().getOut().getString()`

in the `onRequestEnd` function in Application.cfc. This returns a string of HTML just like it's sent to the browser.

You could store that in the appropriate scope (APPLICATION, SESSION, etc) and use it later, or whatever you need. Obviously, all processing needs to be completed, but it shouldn't require any flushes. In fact, flushing may or may not alter its behavior.

Comment: <Obviously, all processing needs to be completed>  @Sean Hogge, why is that true?  I'm trying to get the info to the screen during processing.  Is that not possible in this situation?

Comment: It's probably possible, but may require a different tag. As far as I can tell, those methods are only available after the page has been completely rendered into HTML and is ready to send to the client.

That being said, you may be able to call it sooner, and it may return what it has (I don't have the docs in front of me). My guess is that it won't and you'll have to do somehow catch a flush if I understand what you're trying to do.